# Call prebuilt C++ shared library from Android with JNI

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

I want to use a prebuilt C++ library from Android via JNI. Therefore I am working with Android Studio.

I am building the project with com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.7.0-alpha4 and my build.gradle looks like this:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.model.application"

model {
    repositories {
        libs(PrebuiltLibraries) {
            rexxlib {
                binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinary) {
                    sharedLibraryFile = file("src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/librexx.so")
                }
            }
            rexxapilib {
                binaries.withType(SharedLibraryBinary) {
                    sharedLibraryFile = file("src/main/jniLibs/armeabi/librexxapi.so")
                }
            }
        }
    }



    android {
        compileSdkVersion 23
        buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"

        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "org.oorexx.oorexxforandroid"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel 19
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel 23
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            buildConfigFields {
                create() {
                    type "int"
                    name "VALUE"
                    value "1"
                }
            }
        }

        ndk {
            moduleName "rexxwrapper"
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles.add(file("proguard-rules.pro"))
            }
        }

        // Configures source set directory.
        sources {
            main {
                java {
                    source {
                        srcDir "src/main/java"
                    }
                }
                jniLibs {
                    dependencies {
                        library "rexxlib"
                        library "rexxapilib"
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.3.0'
}
```

I created a wrapper C library to call the prebuilt library from there.

```
#include "org_oorexx_oorexxforandroid_jniwrapper_RexxWrapper.h"
#include <jni.h>

JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_org_oorexx_oorexxforandroid_jniwrapper_RexxWrapper_callrexx(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance) {

    //TODO: call function of prebuilt library librexx.so - What todo?

    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "Hello From Jni");
}
```

My Java class for the wrapper:

```
public class RexxWrapper {

    private native String callrexx();

    static public void execute(String argv[]) {
        RexxWrapper rexxWrapper = new RexxWrapper();
        System.out.println("--> "+rexxWrapper.callrexx());
    }

    static {
        System.loadLibrary("rexx");
        System.loadLibrary("rexxwrapper");
    }

}
```

I have created a test-method in my shared library (C++) which looks like this:

```
int AndroidRexxStart()
{
    return 1;
}
```

Everything is working fine, and I get the response from my wrapper c library. Now I want to call a function `AndroidRexxStart()` of the prebuilt library `librexx.so` in my wrapper library and I do not know how to do that. What I have to include and how can I call the method?

EDIT: 
My Projectstructure:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've made a Java wrapper for the library but you also need to make a JNI wrapper for the Java to call. So you'll need JNI methods for each of the library methods you want to call. I don't know what LibRexx is so I don't know what you would want to call but you just need to expose those in JNI so they can be called from Java.

First, you're rexxWrapper should be linking in librexx so you shouldn't need to load it in Java. Second you can just create another JNI method like this:

```
JNIEXPORT jint JNICALL Java_org_oorexx_oorexxforandroid_jniwrapper_RexxWrapper_start(JNIEnv *env, jobject instance) {

    return AndroidRexxStart();
}
```

Then in your `AndroidRexxStart()` you would actually call into the librexx to start it.

In Java you'll add:

```
private native String start();
```

to call the JNI method. The naming of the JNI method is important. It has to match the Java path, class and method name that you want to use.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I have a added my test method in the shared library in the post. Maybe you can give me some more information what to do, based on my example.

Comment: So you mean I should be able to call the `AndroidRexxStart()` function directly from my `rexxwrapper.c`?

Comment: Yeah. I mean, that's an option. It will come down to how you want to organize your code but that's the idea.

Comment: Ok - because if I try that the gradle build throws an error: `Error:(12) undefined reference to 'AndroidRexxStart'` -  `Error:Execution failed for task ':app:linkRexxwrapperArmeabi-v7aDebugSharedLibrary'.`

Comment: Are you including the file with AndroidRexxStart into your JNI file?

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you mean. What should I include?

Comment: Is the `AndroidRexxStart()` method in the same file as your JNI code? If it's not then you need to include whatever file it's in. If it is in the same file then it has to be above where it's being used.

Comment: No, the `AndroidRexxStart()` is the function in the prebuilt shared library that I want to call - so it is not in my JNI code. Problem is I want to include the *.h file where the method is, but I do not know how. I tried with `#include<librexx/rexx.h> ` and also other options. It always ends up with a build error: `Error:(3, 23) librexx/rexx.h: No such file or directory`.

Comment: Ok, so generall C++ programming. When you're using a precompiled library you need two things. You need the library, for Android this will be an .so or a .a file and you need the header files. You need to either have them installed somewhere on your system path, tell your compiler where to find them or have them in your project directory. I'm guessing the easiest thing for you would be to copy them into your project directory and include them from there.

Comment: If you look at the helloLibs example that comes with the NDK it will show you how to get this set up.

Comment: In this moment I am adding the header files - I did not understand that I need the header files additionally to the shared library.

Comment: Thank you @CaseyB - I re-structed everything (equal to the helloLibs example) and now it is working.